# Subordinated non-deterministic Gaussian process is non-deterministic

Tags: pr.probability, time-series

Let $X = \{ X(k), k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be a strictly stationary, Gaussian time series whose spectral density $f_X$ exists.
Furthermore, let $X$ be non-deterministic, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[ \vert X(n + 1) - \mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{M}_n(X)} X(n + 1)\vert^2\big] > 0,
\quad
n \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
where $\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{M}_n(X)} X(n + 1)$ is the projection of $X(n + 1)$ onto $\mathcal{M}_n(X) := \overline{\text{span}} \{X(k),\ k \leq n \}$.

For $u > 0$, show that $Y$ defined by $Y(k) = \mathbb{1} \{\vert X(k) \vert > u\}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, is non-deterministic as well.

### Possible intermediate steps

- The indicator function $\mathbb{1}\{\vert x \vert \leq u\}$ has a Hermite expansion with coefficients as given in [1].
- I was able to show that $Y$ has a spectral density $f_Y$. This could be useful to show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log f_Y(t) \mathrm{d}t > - \infty$ (which is a sufficient condition for non-deterministicness, cf. Remark 1, p.192 in [2]). However, I could only prove the existence of $f_Y$ and do not have an explicit form.

### References

[1] Kagawa, T., Yoshino, K. The Hermite expansion of the characteristic functions. J. Pseudo-Differ. Oper. Appl. 8, 255–273 (2017). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11868-017-0188-x

[2] Brockwell, P. J., & Davis, R. A. (1991). Time Series: Theory and Methods. In Springer Series in Statistics. Springer New York. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-0320-4